# HLSL Array Indexing Returning Unexpected Values

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl

I am executing some HLSL code on the GPU in Unity, but I am having issues with getting values out of an array. Here is my simplified code example.

C#

```
ComputeBuffer meshVerticesBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(
  15 * 1,
  sizeof(float) * 3
);
marchingCubesShader.SetBuffer(0, "MeshVertices", meshVerticesBuffer);
marchingCubesShader.Dispatch(0, 1, 1, 1);

Vector3[] meshVertices = new Vector3[15 * 1];
meshVerticesBuffer.GetData(meshVertices);
meshVerticesBuffer.Release();
```

HLSL

```
#pragma kernel ApplyMarchingCubes

int EDGE_TABLE[][15] = {
    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    ...255 more irrelevant entries
};

RWStructuredBuffer<float3> MeshVertices;

[numthreads(4, 4, 4)]
void ApplyMarchingCubes(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    MeshVertices[0] = float3(0, 0, EDGE_TABLE[0][0]);
}
```

I am watching `meshVertices` on the C# side through the debugger, and the first item is always a `Vector3(0, 0, 0)`. I am expecting a result of `Vector3(0, 0, -1)`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why the array was not putting out the right values.
In HLSL, when declaring and initializing an array in the same line, you must include the `static` keyword.

My HLSL code should have been:

```
#pragma kernel ApplyMarchingCubes

static int EDGE_TABLE[][15] = {
    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    ...255 more irrelevant entries
};

RWStructuredBuffer<float3> MeshVertices;

[numthreads(4, 4, 4)]
void ApplyMarchingCubes(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    MeshVertices[0] = float3(0, 0, EDGE_TABLE[0][0]);
}
```

(Notice `static` on the third line, it was not there before).